# How to disable "Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How to disable the following warning in Xcode:

Values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead

Please note that I want to disable the warning only, I know can cast the NSInteger to long, but I don't want to.

Comment: Did you find the actual way to build the app anyway? It's not letting me after updating to the latest xcode

Comment: @octohedron No, I didn't. I think %zd works for Mac (64bit) but not for iOS where you can get both 32bit and 64bit

Answer (score -1):

You can just use %zd for NSInteger instead disable warning use #pragma